# pinescript - simple string is expected error: how to call security with a string array element?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im trying to simplify my code by using an array to store ticker values.  However when i call the security function using an element of that array as the symbol arguement, i get the error:

```
Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'symbol'='ticker'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected
```

Here is what the code looks like

```
period = timeframe.period
arr = str.split("FB AAPL TSLA MSFT AMZN NFLX GOOG NVDA", " ")
for i = 0 to array.size(arr) -1 
    ticker = array.get(arr, i)
    series = request.security(ticker, period)
    plot(series)
```

Does anyone know the recommended way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that because of the casting rules. `str.split()` returns `series string` and you acnnot cast that to `simple string`.

[image]

You must call the `security()` function separately for each ticker.

Comment: you mean i must hard code the tickers one by one..no way to loop through a common data structure like an array containing strings?  I've tried generating an 'input_string' from the array elements ...same error it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Plus, you cannot use `plot()` in local scope so, your code wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: oy..first day playing with pinescript..seems very limiting.  thanks for trying to help

Comment: Is there a solution now?

Comment: @Diger No, there isn't.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if you have any affiliations, but this really needs to get added...