# Pine V5 type issues : Display RSI value on tradingview chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to display the RSI value above each bar in trading view.
I'm not able to do so because no matter what I try I get the following error.

> Cannot call 'plotshape' with argument 'text'='vt_rsi_str'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected

I'm clearly going about this wrong, but I feel like displaying the RSI value is something that should be possible, no?

The latest grasping at straws syntax I've tried is below.
Any suggestions would appreciated!

```
vt_rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
vt_rsi_str = str.format("{0,number,#}", str.tostring(vt_rsi[0]))
plotshape(vt_rsi_up, style=shape.arrowup, color=#1848cc, title="RSI Up", location=location.top, text=vt_rsi_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not supported with `plot()` functions. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237240/pinescript-simple-string-is-expected-error-how-to-call-security-with-a-string/70237329#70237329) for more details.

However, you can use `label`s instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
vt_rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
vt_rsi_str = str.format("{0,number,#.##}", vt_rsi)
label1 = label.new(bar_index, high, text=vt_rsi_str, style=label.style_triangledown, size=size.tiny, color=#1848cc, textcolor=#1848cc)
label.set_xloc(label1, time, xloc.bar_time)
label.set_y(label1, high)
label.set_text(label1, vt_rsi_str)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful.
I wish I could get the labels to go across the top of the screen like I could with the plotshape. :(